# Find n^th entry in a column where n is an integer in another column in excel

Tags: excel, lookup, match

I used `match` to find a row number for the best match between columns 1 and 2. Now I would like to use that number from match, which is really just an integer telling me which entry in the column selection I need to use, to lookup the value in column 3.

So if `match` spits back 28, how do I lookup the 28th entry in column A11:A60?

Can I do this in excel? (it is all I am allowed to use) Thanks! Never use excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `INDEX()` function.

My first guess would be something around:

```
=INDEX(A11:A60; 28)
```

Comment: Certainly a neater answer than mine! Needs a comma though, not a semi-cololn.

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty slick. I was searching for things like "which" and "lookup".

Comment: @Dave. Hmm. That might be a locale thing, but my Excel (2003) accepts only a semi-colon as arguments separator. It doesn't take a comma.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it must be. It won't accept a semi-colon here! Typical Microsoft trying to confuse us.

Answer (score 0):

If match sticks the answer in cell A10, then in cell A9 you could have the formula:

```
=ADDRESS(10+A10,1)
```

Where 10 means row 10 (above your A11), and the 1 means column A

So you should see:

```
$A$38
```

Then you can use indirect to get the value from that cell:

```
=INDIRECT(A9)
```

And that will give you what you're looking for